# Which type of visa should my family have if I have business visa for Belgium?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, family, belgium, visa-sponsors

I have to renew my business visa for Belgium, this time I want to take my wife & child with me.

- For them the visa category would be tourist only.?
- Can I submit their application (tourist visa) along with mine (business visa)?
- My wife is not working, she is home maker, so I have to submit a sponsorship letter mentioning that I will be covering her expenses ?

Comment: what nationality are you and your wife? If for instance your wife is a EU citizen, you don't need any visa.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**:
Yes to all 3 questions.

---

Each applicant must apply for a visa

- even in cases where a 'Family' Passport exists

Multiple reasons can be given that must be specific to each applicant

- **Tourism** and **Business**
- **Tourism** only

Field 33 is where the **sponsorship** should be noted

- **other (please specify):**

  - the extremely tiny area could be used to reference an accompanying letter
- check **All expenses covered during the stay**

Submitting all applications togeather *may* avoid multiple copies of the needed documentation. A covering letter with the **sponsor** Application stating that they are sponsoring their spouse/children would not harm in case the applications get separated.

**Note**:
Family members of EU-Citizens that **need a visa**

- do **not** need to fill out the Fields that contain a '*' before the field number
- but instead must fill out the Fields 34 and 35

---

As a *general statement* (made as a comment to this question)

> > If for instance your wife is a EU citizen, you don't need any visa.

is **only** correct when the answer to the following question is **yes**:

**Is the visa applicant accompanying or joining the EU citizen?**

- **accompanies** (i.e. travels *together* with) an EU citizen:
- **joins** (i.e. travels *later* than) an EU citizen:

> The Directive seeks to facilitate and promote free movement of EU citizens. It **does not apply to mobility of the family members** if there is no link to a mobile EU citizens, for example when **the family member travels alone** to a Member State in which the **EU citizen does not reside and will not travel to**.

**2.3 Visa exemption under the Schengen Borders Code**
gives the following sample:

> A Slovak citizen resides with his Chinese spouse in Ireland. The Chinese spouse holding a residence card, issued by Ireland under Article 10 of the Directive, travels alone to France. **As she travels alone, she needs to apply for a visa to enter France**

---

Information is based on:

- [Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modifictaion of issued visas](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/20140709_visa_code_handbook_consolidated_en.pdf) as pdf

  - 14.05.2019

Usage of the term **EU citizen**: EU/EEA and Swiss citizens.

- [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32004L0038)

Answer (score 0):

> For them the visa category would be tourist only?

Yes.

> Can I submit their application (tourist visa) along with me (business visa)?

Yes.