# What is the Netherlands visa category to pick if you're attending a conference and accompanied by your spouse for tourism

Tags: visas, schengen, tourist-visas, netherlands, spouses

I'm planning to attend a conference in The Netherlands (Amsterdam) in the month of April 2023. My spouse would be accompanying me on the trip purely for tourism reasons.

When applying for the visa via vfs global, what Visa category would I pick ? As I see it there is a separate option as `Conference`. But cannot pick a different option for each applicant.

My spouse and I would be jointly funding this trip. Any help/clarifications on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but are you saying that all those travelling are applying together under a single application? It is more typical for the principal traveller to apply and then the rest of the group/family make separate applications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which type of visa should my family have if I have business visa for Belgium?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147560/which-type-of-visa-should-my-family-have-if-i-have-business-visa-for-belgium)

Comment: It might help to state where you and your spouse are from.

Comment: @Traveller thanks for sharing the other question. it is very helpful :) in vfs global portal, I see an option to add multiple applicants within the same application. Hence my question.

Comment: @Abigail we're both from India

Comment: @niranjan94 Can you post a screenshot of the multiple applicants option you’re referring to?